# Data Design debate

Tags: sql, database-design

I am having a tough time with this design problem and would appreciate any insight.

I have a doctors office that is provided certain privileges currently there are only 5 privileges but more could be added. Each of these privileges has a status of Yes or No, but there could be a finer grained status in the future and each of these privileges are related to a location(er,inpatient, outpatient) and they too could expand in future.

So currently I have the tables OfficePrivileges, PrivilegeLocation, PrivilegeType, PrivilegeStatus.

OfficePrivilege is a Joining table between PrivilegeLocation and DoctorOffice. It has a double primary key of OfficeID and PrivilegeLocationID.

At one time I had Type and status joined to the OfficePrivileges Table then switched to have the type table be a child of Location and status be a child of type. They are all single primary key tables.

**if you were designing this set of tables how would you do it?** I am thinking that this is almost a hierarchy problem..and I hate them. I would like to lay out the edit screen as crosstab table having Location across the top, Type down the side and details being the statuses. That is how it is currently in the system I am trying to integrate to, but its a Cobol backend and handles hierarchies better than relational db....

**EDIT:To Help clear up confusion:**

For my example there are Admit Privileges, Attending Privileges,Consulting privileges and Surgery Privilges. And the locations are Inpatient, ER, OutPatient, and OP/Surgery. Currently the statuses are only Yes or NO. But they could change in the future depending on client need.

This information is stored in tables in my database.

Comment: You might find Access Control Lists (ACL) interesting.

Comment: how do the privileges actually work? is it all or nothing? or should some users have read only access? or edit but not delete?

Comment: @scunliffe: I believe he's talking about Hospital Privileges.  In the medical world, if a Doctor can send you to a specific hospital, that doctor has "privileges" at that hospital.

Comment: right sorry this is about doctor privileges. for example. Doctor A has admit privileges in the ER but not the OutPatient Area.

for my example there are Admit Privileges, Attending Privileges,Consulting privileges and Surgery Privilges. And the locations are Inpatient, ER, OutPatient, and OP/Surgery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the big thing here it to try to be as flexible as possible, since you're aware of "possible" changes, but you don't really want to code to those, yet.

Something like what you've got is really probably pretty good:  I'd go this way: you'll actually have a 3-way relationship between Offices, PrivilegeLocations, and PrivilegeTypes

I would say your OfficePrivaleges table should have the following 6 columns: `Id (its own PK), OfficeId, LocationId, PTypeId, StartDate, EndDate`  When a new Privilege is granted for an Office, you'll add a record to this table linking the three and adding the first date the office has the privilege in `StartDate`.  If the Privilege is revoked, add that date to `EndDate`.  If it's renabled, either add a new row, or reset the `StartDate`.

I would avoid making PrivilegeType a child of PrivilegeLocation, because then you either have to store every location `n` times (`n` = different privilege combinations).  This way, you're only storing Offices, Locations, and Types once each.

So, for instance, Doctor A could have Inpatient Privileges at Location X, but only DX Imaging privileges at Location Y, while Doctor B could have Inpatient privileges at both Locations X and Y.

Comment: so the way I was going in the beginning would be my best bet...

OfficePrivileges
 OfficeId
 LocationId
 PTypeId
 StatusId(instead of Startdate Enddate)

Could I make the Primary a double key of OfficeId and LocationId? That way each office would only be allowed one location...Of course I could do that in my code as well..

Comment: @ecathell  you could do that (or set a constraint, or any number of things).  But is that accurate?  My doctor, for instance, has admitting privileges at atleast two (and I think 3) local hospitals.

Comment: this is only for one hospital's system. This application would be specifically for a single hospital. its geared for the hospital and not the doctor... heh...am I being redundant :)